# Rows count bug on Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have this sequelize sentence:

```
const results = await Workflow.findAndCountAll({limit: limit, offset: offset, where: { userId: userId }, include: [ WorkflowStep ]  });
```

Workflow object has a relationship with steps 1:m with WorkflowStep, passing `null` as `limit` and `offset = 0` this is the response I got:

[image: Response]

As you can the `count` value is counting the association values count and not the main object count, I think this is bug right, count should be only `2` that is the number of records in the `rows` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be a Bug I found the solution here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9481 and they said using `distinct: true` solve the issue